# Which Linux Distro is widely used for pentesting

Tags: linux

I want to start to learn pentesting and wanted to know what is the most widely used Linux distro that is best to learn on?

Comment: This type of question is out of scope.  The Linux distribution you should use for pentesting is the one your most familiar with.  The reason this type of question is out of scope here is really simply, you are going to get lots of answers which state user's opinions, most won't be able to or more importantly will not provide facts to support their opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) is a Live Linux distro that is specifically created for penetration testing.  Their site has a lot of good documentation and a large community.  It comes pre-bundled with a lot of tools for testing many common attack vectors.